# Same debit card number issued to more than one account?

Tags: fraud

I received text alerts from my bank saying my debit card had beeen used when I hadn’t used it. I started a fraud alert investigation. I was later told another account had the exact same debit card number except the last two numbers.  The cvv code was the same on both accounts/cards.  Is this possible??

Comment: *" the exact same debit card number except the last two numbers"* - if it is different by two numbers than it is clearly not the same. The title is misleading.

Comment: This is not an information security question at all.